# How many 'genius' levels are there on booking.com?

Tags: booking.com

booking.com tells you what level of 'genius' you are, but not how many levels there are in total. How many levels are there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 levels. [Genius levels on Booking.com](https://www.booking.com/genius.html) tells you your level.

#### Level 1

- 10% discounts

#### Level 2

- 10%-15% discounts
- Free breakfasts on select stays
- Free room upgrades on select stays

#### Level 3

- 10%-20% discounts
- Free breakfasts on select stays
- Free room upgrades on select stays
- Priority support on all bookings

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the 3 Genius levels, there is also a "Genius VIP" reward that can be unlocked by being one of Booking.com's best customers (for me, it unlocked after I made 9 bookings in a 4 month period, and I am currently at Genius Level 2). It gives you an extra 5% discount on any property that is designated "VIP reward". Genius VIP only lasts for 2 months after you unlock it.

[image]